# Okta management api within Azure logic app - retrieve header with duplicate key

Tags: azure, pagination, header, azure-logic-apps

Using logic apps to extract some logs from Okta and come across an interesting issue.

The okta management api paginates the responses and provide the link to the next list of paginated responses in a 'Link' header; however they also provide another 'Link' header which gives you the link to the current page.

Ie:

```
link : <https://dev1-web.okta.com/api/v1/logs?since=2022-07-07T20%3A19%3A.0837307Z&sortOrder=ASCENDING>; rel="self"
link : <https://dev1-web.okta.com/api/v1/logs?since=2022-07-07T20%3A19%3A.0837307Z&sortOrder=ASCENDING&after=1657289356194_1>; rel="next"
```

When retrieving the headers from the http call it merges them as:

```
<https://dev-web.okta.com/api/v1/logs?since=2022-07-07T20%3A19%3A.0837307Z&sortOrder=ASCENDING>; rel="self",<https://dev-web.okta.com/api/v1/logs?since=2022-07-07T20%3A19%3A.0837307Z&sortOrder=ASCENDING&after=1657289356194_1>; rel="next"
```

I am trying to find a way to pull the link header out which has the rel="next" wihtout having to add a load of condition logic to check which side of the split has the rel="next". Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't find the response to be in any format, One of the workarounds that can meet the requirement is to extract the link using string functions such as `lastIndexOf` and `slice` functions in Compose connector. Here is my logic app flow.

[image]

Below is the expression I'm using in my compose connector.

```
slice(outputs('Compose'),add(lastIndexOf(outputs('Compose'),'<'),1),lastIndexOf(outputs('Compose'),'>'))
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]

Below is the code-view of my logic app

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "link : <https://dev1-web.okta.com/api/v1/logs?since=2022-07-07T20%3A19%3A.0837307Z&sortOrder=ASCENDING>; rel=\"self\"\nlink : <https://dev1-web.okta.com/api/v1/logs?since=2022-07-07T20%3A19%3A.0837307Z&sortOrder=ASCENDING&after=1657289356194_1>; rel=\"next\"",
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Compose_2": {
                "inputs": "@slice(outputs('Compose'),add(lastIndexOf(outputs('Compose'),'<'),1),lastIndexOf(outputs('Compose'),'>'))",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Consider if you are receiving a JSON response, then you can parse the response and can extract it directly.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this - I can't seem to get the inputs working. I have updated the question above to better explain

Comment: @Webezine I have tried the same with your updated output. Can you please try using the code view in some sample logic app cuz I see its working from my end.